# When using SSH is it possible to prevent password authentication only if a certificate exists in the user's home directory?

Tags: sshd, authentication, key-authentication

I am spinning up a public facing server with SSH running for remote access. Every standard human user will be using a certificate for authentication.

However one very limited functional account exists on the machine that automatic software will use to login to, but do not support using certificates for authentication.

I'd like SSHd to reject any attempts to password authentication on all user accounts that contain a certificate but allow password authentication on user accounts who don't.

Comment: I think you can use PAM to configure that per user, but I'd have to look up details. Alternatively, `AuthenticationMethods` in a conditional block in `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the users can change their own certificates themselves, every once in a while someone will make a mistake and erase their existing certificate. If this causes the account to revert to password authentication, the users might learn this and exploit it intentionally.

Instead, set the default settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to only accept certificate authentication, then create a `Match User` block at the end of the configuration file that overrides the default to allow password authentication to that user only. Or if there might be other users with password authentication, make it a `Match Group` block and create a custom group to which you'll add any users that need password-authenticated SSH access.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for the explanation and solution. I've never had to use the Match User/Group in sshd_config before--it didn't even occur to me.